# how to make a biplot without label in R

Tags: r

I used

```
biplot(prcomp(data, scale.=T), xlabs=rep("·", nrow(data)))
```

but it did not work to omit the labels.
Even if I remove the labels my plot is so messy and ugly which can be seen below! 
I also need to show the percentage of PCs on axes 
[image]

I used the following command to plot the image

```
biplot(prcomp(data, scale.=T), xlabs=rep("·", nrow(data)), ylabs = rep("·", ncol(data)))
```

Comment: Your question is not [`reproducible`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But your approach should work ex. `biplot(prcomp(USArrests, scale.=T), xlabs=rep("·", nrow(USArrests)))`

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the `ylabs` as well? Then just use `biplot(princomp(USArrests, scales=TRUE), 
       xlabs = rep("·", nrow(USArrests)), 
       ylabs = rep(".", ncol(USArrests))
       )`

Comment: unfortunately I cannot publish my data but I just want to get rid of labels since my data is huge , look at the above plot even if I remove the labels it becomes so ugly

Comment: [Here are a few tips](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on how to reproduce your problem. If there's too much data, you can always simulate some and pass on the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
\devtools::install_github("sinhrks/ggfortify")
library(ggfortify)
ggplot2::autoplot(stats::prcomp(USArrests, scale=TRUE), label = FALSE, loadings.label = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your nice comment. my data is huge and this make it so ugly ! does not show the precentage of PCs on plot neither !